.Net Maui Dependency Injection issue with custom service
I'm attempting to implement Firebase Crashlytics in my .Net MUI 8 app using the following example:
https://dev.to/vhugogarcia/firebase-crashlytics-in-net-maui-57jp
However, I'm having issues understanding how to access the registered FirebaseCrashlyticsService.
The following crashes with "System Null Reference Exception":
var firebaseCrashlyticsService = Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetServices<IFirebaseCrashlyticsService>();

My MauiProgram.cs is as follows:
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
using MyApp.Services.Firebase;
using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;

namespace MyApp;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkitMediaElement()
            .RegisterFirebase()
            .RegisterAppServices();

        return builder.Build();
    }

    private static MauiAppBuilder RegisterFirebase(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
#if IOS
            events.AddiOS(iOS => iOS.FinishedLaunching((app, launchOptions) => {
                Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
                Firebase.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.SharedInstance.Init();
                Firebase.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.SharedInstance.SetCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
                Firebase.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.SharedInstance.SendUnsentReports();
                return false;
            }));
#else
            events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, bundle) => {
                Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(activity);
            }));
#endif
        });

        return builder;
    }

    public static MauiAppBuilder RegisterAppServices(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFirebaseCrashlyticsService, FirebaseCrashlyticsService>();

        return builder;
    }
}


what does the stack trace show?  Which element of that statement is null?

You can also refer to the official doc about Handler.


However, I'm having issues understanding how to access the registered FirebaseCrashlyticsService.
The following crashes with "System Null Reference Exception":
var firebaseCrashlyticsService = Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetServices<IFirebaseCrashlyticsService>();


You can add it to OnHandlerChanged Method:
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //var firebaseCrashlyticsService = Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetServices<IFirebaseCrashlyticsService>();
}

protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
    base.OnHandlerChanged();

    var firebaseCrashlyticsService = Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetServices<IFirebaseCrashlyticsService>();
}

